# Como eu acesso elementos de um json que contém várias chaves no python?

Tags: python, json, array, api

Eu estou praticando o aprendizado de apis com a HG finances , porém quando vou filtrar as informações através de um FOR , vejo que apresenta um erro chamado `KeyError: nome da moeda`, porém o código roda da mesma forma , gostaria de entender como faço para retirar a exata informação de um json com vários arrays e como retirar esse erro. segue meu codigo abaixo:

```
import requests
arquivo = open('C:/Users/Usuario/PycharmProjects/Aprendizado/ pass.txt', mode='r')
senha =arquivo.read()
requests= requests.get("https://api.hgbrasil.com/finance/quotations?key={}".format(senha))
dados = requests.json()
moeda= input("Moeda Desejada: ")
for x in dados['results'].values():
    for z in x[moeda].items():
        print(z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas é passando as keys(chaves) de forma explicita:

```
import requests
requests= requests.get("https://api.hgbrasil.com/finance/quotations?key={}")
dados = requests.json()

moeda = input("Moeda Desejada: ").upper()

for item in dados['results']['currencies'][moeda].items():
    print(item)
```

Entrada:

```
Moeda Desejada: usd
```

Saída:

```
('name', 'Dollar')
('buy', 5.393)
('sell', 5.4116)
('variation', 0.04)
```

---

Pode exibir tudo em uma linha também:

```
dados['results']['currencies'][moeda]
```

Saída:

```
{'name': 'Dollar', 'buy': 5.393, 'sell': 5.4116, 'variation': 0.04}
```